# Rich push notification not working in iPhone 11 Pro Max in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to show the image on the push notification alert. This is working fine for other devices like iPhone X, iPhone XR, iPhone 7. But unfortunately, this doesn't work with iPhone 11 Pro Max. My client has iPhone 11 Pro Max hence I can't debug the issue.

[image: iPhone X]

[image: iPhone 11 Pro Max]

I am getting the code from push notification payload and downloading the image from that code.

I have created an extension of "Notification Service Extension"

```
 - (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent *_Nonnull))contentHandler
 {
self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

NSArray *arr = [self.bestAttemptContent.body componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];
NSString *alertText = self.bestAttemptContent.body;
NSString *stickerMessage = nil;

if (arr.count > 1){
            //Check if text is of sticker
            if ([self isStickerMessage:arr[1]]) {
                alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",arr[0]];
                stickerMessage = arr[1];
            }
    }

// check for media attachment, example here uses custom payload keys mediaUrl and mediaType
if (stickerMessage == nil)
{
    [self contentComplete];
    return;
}

NSCharacterSet* characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"[]"];
NSString* stickerName = [stickerMessage stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: characterSet];

if (stickerName)
{
    self.bestAttemptContent.body = alertText;

    [self loadImagePath:stickerName completionHandler:^(NSString *picURL) {
        if (picURL) {
            [self loadAttachmentForUrlString:picURL
                           completionHandler: ^(UNNotificationAttachment *attachment) {
                               self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:attachment, nil];
                               [self contentComplete];
                           }];
        }
        else{
           [self contentComplete];
        }
    }];

}
```

}

```
 -(void)loadImagePath: (NSString *)stickerName
  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *))completionHandler{

 NSString *apiPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ApiPath,stickerName];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiPath]];

[self headerSetup:req];

//NSString *userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: @"kUserKeyDefaultsKey"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        completionHandler(nil);
    }else if (data){
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        if (dict) {
            //NSURL* urlString = [NSURL URLWithString: dict[@"data"][@"image"][@"mdpi"]];
            //NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
            completionHandler(dict[@"data"][@"image"][[self scaleString]]);
        }
    }
    else{
        completionHandler(nil);
    }

}];
[task resume];
```

}

```
  - (void)loadAttachmentForUrlString:(NSString *)urlString
             completionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationAttachment *))completionHandler
{
__block UNNotificationAttachment *attachment = nil;
__block NSURL *attachmentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSString *fileExt = @".png";//[@"." stringByAppendingString:[urlString pathExtension]];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:attachmentURL
                                            completionHandler: ^(NSURL *temporaryFileLocation, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error != nil)
                                                {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {

                                                    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                                                    NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[temporaryFileLocation.path
                                                                                              stringByAppendingString:fileExt]];
                                                    [fileManager moveItemAtURL:temporaryFileLocation
                                                                         toURL:localURL
                                                                         error:&error];

                                                    NSError *attachmentError = nil;
                                                    attachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:[attachmentURL lastPathComponent]
                                                                                                                URL:localURL
                                                                                                            options:nil
                                                                                                              error:&attachmentError];
                                                    if (attachmentError)
                                                    {
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", attachmentError.localizedDescription);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                completionHandler(attachment);
                                            }];

[task resume];
```

}

```
- (void)contentComplete
{
    //[self.session invalidateAndCancel];
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely to be the phone model. It is more likely to be a network issue or similar that is preventing the download from completing. Why not create a TestFlight build that puts any relevant error message into the notification so you can try and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the issue but i downloaded the image from URL directly instead of using NSURLSessionDataTask & this fixed the issue.

Following are the code I have written

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent *_Nonnull))contentHandler
{
self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

NSArray *arr = [self.bestAttemptContent.body componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];
NSString *alertText = self.bestAttemptContent.body;
NSString *stickerMessage = nil;

if (arr.count > 1){
    //Check if text is of sticker
    if ([self isStickerMessage:arr[1]]) {
        alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",arr[0]];
        stickerMessage = arr[1];
    }
}

// check for media attachment, example here uses custom payload keys mediaUrl and mediaType
if (stickerMessage == nil)
{
    [self contentComplete];
    return;
}

NSCharacterSet* characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"[]"];
NSString* stickerName = [stickerMessage stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: characterSet];

if (stickerName)
{
    NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[fileManger URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];//FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",stickerName];

    NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];



    self.bestAttemptContent.body = alertText;
    NSString *picURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://stickerpipe.com/stk/emojiabc/%@_hdpi.png",stickerName];


    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picURL]];
    if (data) {
        if ([data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:true]) {
            NSError *attachmentError = nil;
            UNNotificationAttachment *attachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:fileName
                                                                                                  URL:fileURL
                                                                                              options:nil
                                                                                                error:&attachmentError];
            self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:attachment, nil];

        }else{
            NSLog(@"Data can't be written");
        }
    }

    [self contentComplete];

  }
 }
```